# Unable to make POST request on mobile devices IONIC ANGULAR

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to send push notification to all devices by invoking a firebase function.

Firebase Function,

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require('cors');
const request = require('request-promise');
const app = express();
const main = express();

main.use(cors())
main.use('/api/v1', app);
main.use(bodyParser.json());
main.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.post('/sendNotification', function(req, res) {  
  console.log(req.body)

  let notification = {
    "to" :  req.body.token,
    "collapse_key" : "type_a",
    "notification" : {
        "body" : "Body of Your Notification",
        "title": "Title of Your Notification"
    },
    "data" : {
        "body" : "Body of Your Notification in Data",
        "title": "Title of Your Notification in Title",
        "key_1" : "Value for key_1",
        "key_2" : "Value for key_2"
    }
   };
    
    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      uri: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
      body: notification,
      json: true,
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'key=MY KEY'
      }
    }
    
    request(options).then(function (response){
      res.status(200).json(response);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      console.log(err);
    })    
});

exports.sendSms = functions.https.onRequest(main);
```

In my Angular Application,

```
  sendNotification() {
    alert('Called, ddd');

    this.http.post(this.settings.sendNotification, { token: this.token }).subscribe(res => {
      alert('API CALLED');
      console.log(res)
    });
  }
```

On my emulator devices, I could see the `sendNotification` function getting called, but the alert inside the API subscribe never executed.

Please help.

Comment: make sure to see if an error occured on device hwne doing the request, could be failed due to non https ink protocols or blocked because of core issues... so make sure of error section even if it succeeded on web testing...

Answer (score 0):

I hope this plugin will solve your problem.

1. Use the below commands for installing the native http plugin.

   npm install cordova-plugin-advanced-http

   npm install @ionic-native/http
2. Import the plugin in your module by using

   import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http/ngx';
3. Then import the same plugin inside your service/page/component and inject  in your constructor. Its **CORS** safe and works only in Android emulator/device.